# Numpy cumsum with boundary conditions to the sum

Tags: python, numpy, cumsum

I have a large matrix [8760,10] where all values are either 50 or -36.  I want to do a cumsum down the columns, where the cumsum cannot be less than 0 or greater than 366.  Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it cannot be less than 0 nor greater than 366, how should we deal with those values? Should it reset? Should it be capped? Please provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: Not sure if interpret the task correctly, but is `cumsum` followed by `clip` not enough? I doubt it's easy to be faster without writing it in a C (lots of logic-overhead for, and this depends on entry-statistics, pretty late short-circuiting). But it's hard to grasp what you ask for exactly: something functional or something as fast as possible.